# Using OR with .val()?

Tags: jquery

How would I use 'OR' in the following example to find if **select** has either example1 OR example2?

```
if($('select').val() === ('example1'||'example2')){
```

Comment: You need to learn about the basics of Javascript operators and boolena logic.

Comment: agreed with @SLaks, you should not go further without reading and learning more about the syntax of javascript.

Comment: Sure, will get stuck into a tutorial. Thanks for the help though guys :)

Comment: Why does the linked question (which is the same as mine) have 10 up votes, while mine has 3 down votes? Life just isn't fair ha ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('select').val() === 'example1' || $('select').val() === 'example2') {
```

Or something that scales a little better,

```
if (!!~['example1', 'example2'].indexOf($('select').val()) {
```

You could also use a `.contains` method that a lot of libraries such as Underscore provide.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('select').val() === 'example1' || $('select').val() === 'example2'){
```